# Javascript Regular Expression allow only one plus (+) sign at start and length of string should not more than 15 character number only

Tags: javascript

Hello All,
                I want JavaScript regular expression which allow (+) sign once at start as well as whole length of string should not be more than 15 numeric  character  i.e 0 to 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`/^\+\d{0,14}$/` - if yours string overall length should be maximum of 15 characters long
`/^\+\d{0,15}$/` - if you want '+' and no more than 15 0-9 characters

You can also experiment on http://regexr.com/

Comment: function phonenumber()
            {
                
                var inputtxt =   document.getElementById('text1').value.trim();
                var phoneno = /^\+\d{15}$/;
                if (inputtxt.match(phoneno)) {
            alert("okay");        
            return true;
                } else {
                    alert("error message");
                    return false;
                }
            }